# How to prevent Apache2 malware execute

Tags: linux, php, security, apache2, hacking

Is there any way to prevent to execute some unwanted malware in Apache2.

One of our clients Wordpress website is hacked and there was a files like /wp-content/uploads/2020/05/U27I0x

Those files seems executable. I showed file content and found below text in a binary.

```
Info: This file is packed with  executable packer t $
$Id:  Copyright (C) 1996-2018 . All Rights Reserved.
```

I want to know that is it possible to setup Apache2 to prevent execution of this type of files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of files were these? .exe? If so then it won't really matter.  You would need to set permissions on the Linux side of things (assuming a Linux webserver).

Linux Permissions are as below, add the numbers up. They then run in the order of user/group/everyone.

3 = Read
2 = Write
1 = Execute

So 777 has the permissions

Read/Write/Execute - User

Read/Write/Execute - Group

Read/Write/Execute - Everyone

Comment: I think it is not exe. I found that it might malware named "ranbyus". It is also known as: Trojan.Win32.Inject.kma (Kaspersky), Trojan-FFJZ!70ED202105FE (McAfee), But I don't know what type of executable file is. Also client programs set permission then I can not manage file permissions. I want know that if it is possible then I explicitly deny to execute this type of files with Apache configuration on http server level.